# Creating paper forms in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

I want to create a handout with dotted lines for the recipient to fill in, a little like this:  [image: this]
 What's the best way to do so? I could imagine doing it as a `tikzpicture`, but that seems clunky. Is there a better way?

Comment: If you'll pardon the 'code golf': `\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}\begin{document}\begin{tabular}{r@{}p{2in}}NAME:&\dotfill\\[2em]EMAIL:&\dotfill\\[2em]MESSAGE:&\dotfill\\&\dotfill\\&\dotfill\\&\dotfill\\&\dotfill\end{tabular}\end{document}`

Comment: Are you expecting the recipient to fill the form in by hand, through interactive PDF or do you want to [create a form class file](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/latex/54-latex-document-classes/342-writing-a-latex-class-file-to-produce-a-form) that the recipient can use to fill in the form via commands?

Comment: For this project, by hand.

Comment: I made good experience with the `textpos` package.

Comment: Yes, this worked for my purpose. Thanks. Sorry I forgot to say so sooner.

Comment: If you want to have forms, you could stick to hyperref (http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf, section 6) or the formular packagehttp://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/formular/formular.pdf package, though haven't worked with the former yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With slightly better formatting than the comment above, here is one way of doing this without `TikZ`:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r@{}p{2in‌​}}
NAME:   &\dotfill\\[2em]
EMAIL:  &\dotfill\\[2em]
MESSAGE:&\dotfill\\
        &\dotfill\\
        &\dotfill\\‌
        ​&\dotfill\\
        &\dotfill
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]